# Matlab function in fmincon with fixed value

Tags: function, matlab

I have a simple model where I want to minimize the RMSE between my dependent variable y and my model values. The model is: `y = alpha + beta'*x`.

For minimization, I am using Matlab's `fmincon` function and am struggling with multiplying my parameter p(2) by x.

MWE:

```
% data
y = [5.072, 7.1588, 7.263, 4.255, 6.282, 6.9118, 4.044, 7.2595, 6.898, 4.8744, 6.5179, 7.3434, 5.4316, 3.38, 5.464, 5.90, 6.80, 6.193, 6.070, 5.737]
x = [18.3447, 79.86538, 85.09788, 10.5211, 44.4556, 69.567, 8.960, 86.197, 66.857, 16.875, 52.2697, 93.971, 24.35, 5.118, 25.126, 34.037, 61.4445, 42.704, 39.531, 29.988]

% initial values
p_initial = [0, 0];

% function: SEE BELOW

objective = @(p) sqrt(mean((y - y_mod(p)).^2));

% optimization
[param_opt, fval] = fmincon(objective, p_initial)
```

If I specify my function as follows then it works.

```
y_mod = @(p) p(1) + p(2).*x
```

However, it does not work if I use the following code. How can I multiply p(2) with x? Where x is not optimized, because the values are given.

```
function f = y_mod(p)

f = p(1) + p(2).*x

end
```

Comment: I think passing `x` as an input into the function `ymod()` might solve the error. `function f = ymod(p,x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the output from a script that has the function declaration:

```
>> modelFitExample2a
RMS Error=0.374, intercept=4.208, slope=0.0388
```

And here is code for the above.  It has many commented lines because it includes alternate ways to fit the data: an inline declaration of `y_mod()`, or a multi-line declaration of `y_mod()`, or no `y_mod()` at all. This version uses the multi-line declaration of `y_mod()`.

```
%modelFitExample2a.m    WCR 2021-01-19
%Reply to stack exchange question on parameter fitting
clear;
global x    %need this if define y_mod() separately, and in that case y_mod() must declare x global

% data
y = [5.0720, 7.1588, 7.2630, 4.2550, 6.2820, 6.9118, 4.0440, 7.2595, 6.8980, 4.8744...
     6.5179, 7.3434, 5.4316, 3.3800, 5.4640, 5.9000, 6.8000, 6.1930, 6.0700, 5.7370];
x = [18.3447,79.8654,85.0979,10.5211,44.4556,69.5670, 8.9600,86.1970,66.8570,16.8750,...
     52.2697,93.9710,24.3500, 5.1180,25.1260,34.0370,61.4445,42.7040,39.5310,29.9880];

% initial values
p_initial = [0, 0];

%predictive model with parameter p
%y_mod = @(p) p(1) + p(2)*x;

% objective function
%If you use y_mod(), then you must define it somewhere
objective = @(p) sqrt(mean((y - y_mod(p)).^2)); 
%objective = @(p) sqrt(mean((y-p(1)-p(2)*x).^2));

% optimization
options = optimset('Display','Notify');
[param_opt, fval] = fmincon(objective,p_initial,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);

% display results
fprintf('RMS Error=%.3f, intercept=%.3f, slope=%.4f\n',...
    fval,param_opt(1),param_opt(2));

%function declaration: predictive model 
%This is an alternative to the inline definition of y_mod() above.
function f = y_mod(p)

global x
f = p(1) + p(2)*x;

end
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I need to define global in addition also outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

carl,
The second method, in which you declare `y_mod()` explicitly (at the end of your script, or in a separate file y_mod.m), does not work because `y_mod()` does not know what `x` is.  Fix it by declaring `x` global in the main program at the top, and declare `x` global in `y_mod()`.

```
%function declaration
function f = y_mod(p)

global x
f = p(1) + p(2)*x;

end
```

Of course you don't need `y_mod()` at all.  The code also works if you use the following, and in this case, no `global x` is needed:

```
% objective function
objective = @(p) sqrt(mean((y-p(1)-p(2)*x).^2));
```

By the way, you don't need to multiply with `.*` in y_mod. You may use `*`, because you are multiplying a scalar by a vector.

Comment: Is it possible for you to run the code with this function declaration? When I run my script with this function, the following error appears: "Error using  -  Matrix dimensions must agree".

Comment: Carl, Yes it i possible to run the code with the funciton dclaration, and I have done so.  I will paste the code into thi box, also the comment boxes do not support formatting as code

Comment: It seems I cannot have separate lines in a comment, so I will post the code that runs (which in cludes a function declaration) as a separate answer to your question.